# How to filter video that only you like in MediaStore in android?

Tags: android, android-query

Is there other ways to get only video that you like, not all video in the folder is included.

w

```
videoCursorArtist = getContentResolver().query(sourceUri, projection,
                null, selectionArgs, orderByARTIST);
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do that like so :

```
String[] arrayOfString = { "_data" };
        mediaCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, arrayOfString, null, null, null);
        if ((mediaCursor != null) && (mediaCursor.getCount() > 0))
        {
          dataIdx = mediaCursor.getColumnIndex("_data");
          playNextVideo();
        }
```

Comment: example i have a folder video, vid1, vid2, vid3, i dont want to include vid2 in the query, how to do it? because i want to filter the video before aplying the cursor to the Adapter in listview.

Comment: To be honest, i'm not sure, never needed something like that. Googling on this shows me you're able to get the name of the video by doing mediaCursor.getString(0). Maybe you can do something like if mediacursor.getstring(2) != null skip video and go to the next one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329500/sqlite-how-to-get-string-items-using-cursor-android for more info

Comment: how about is it possible to drop a row in cursor?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that, try creating a new question

Comment: How to drop a columnIndex in a cursor, is it posible?