# How to retrieve all data form sqlite database into a listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

How to display all data from sqlite to a list view?

Every time I click the "view all button", only one data is displaying even if i add multiple data. how can i display all of my data?

Thank you!

Here are my codes:

MainActivity.java

```
if(view==btnViewAll){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_all);

       TextView id = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idno);
       TextView name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
       TextView grade = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.grade);
        TextView school = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.school);
        TextView program = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.program);
        TextView course = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.course);
        TextView email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
        TextView bday = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bday);
        TextView address = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);
        TextView  gender = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gender);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT *  FROM student", null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            id.setText(c.getString(0));
            name.setText(c.getString(1));
            grade.setText(c.getString(2));
            school.setText(c.getString(3));
            program.setText(c.getString(4));
            course.setText(c.getString(5));
            email.setText(c.getString(6));
            bday.setText(c.getString(7));
            address.setText(c.getString(8));
            gender.setText(c.getString(9));
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is the layout where i want to display all my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUW41.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why code extra when you can do it with some very litle code.

First make a POJO or Bean class for the required data.

```
public class Student {
   String ID,name,grade,school,program,course,email,bday,address,gender;
   (getter and setter)
}
```

Next just create a list of "Student" class and call the SQLite query like this -

```
 List<Student> studentDetailsList= new ArrayList<>();
 studentDetailsList = db.rawQuery("SELECT *  FROM student", null);
```

and you can access it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your question first? Do you want to display multiple students, or multiple data fields in the student database? See here for some help.

[Sqlite how to get string items using cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329500/sqlite-how-to-get-string-items-using-cursor)

Instead of getString, use getColumnIndex() Because column numbers can change. Also can you show your database?

Answer (score 0):

```
     store data in arraylist and pass this list to adapter.
    Make class Student

public class Student {
String ID,name,grade,school,program,course,email,bday,address,gender;
(getter and setter)
}

        EX : 
        ArrayList<Student> studentDetailsList= new ArrayList<>();   


         Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT *  FROM student", null);

                    if (c.moveToFirst()){
                       Student s = new Student();
                       s.setID(c.getString(0));
                    s.setName(c.getString(1));
                    s.setGrade(c.getString(2));
                    s.setSchool(c.getString(3));
                    s.setProgram(c.getString(4));
                    s.setCourse(c.getString(5));
                    s.setEmail(c.getString(6));
                    s.setBday(c.getString(7));
                    s.setAddress(c.getString(8));
                    s.setGender(c.getString(9));
                    }
        studentDetailsList.add(s);


    Now pass this list to adapter and then set data to views


In adapter:

Student ss = studentDetailsList.get(position);
//now set data to your textviews
//ex. youridtextview.setText(ss.getID);
```