# Inserting Data to Mysql Server as json String - No Data uploading

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

Referring to various examples over stack, I wrote below code to send data to MySQL server table, but nothing is uploading there. Here is code for my Android method.

```
 public void sendtoserver(final String data) {
        Log.e("LWFAB", "Sending Data to Server");
        //Send data to server now
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL bulkdataurl = new URL("http://myphp.php?");
                    HttpURLConnection bulkcon = (HttpURLConnection) bulkdataurl.openConnection();
                    bulkcon.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                    bulkcon.setReadTimeout(15000);
                    bulkcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    bulkcon.setDoOutput(true);
                    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(bulkcon.getOutputStream());
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(bufferedOutputStream));
                    bufferedWriter.write(data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    bufferedOutputStream.close();
                    bulkcon.connect();
                    //OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(bulkcon.getOutputStream());
                    //outputStreamWriter.write(data);
                    //outputStreamWriter.flush();

                    //Get Server Response
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bulkcon.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
                    bufferedReader.close();

                    System.out.println("Sending Bulk Data " + bulkcon);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
}
```

I m not getting any error. Below is my php code

```
<?php
require_once("../dbconnect.php"); 

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
error_log(print_r($obj, true));
$array_data = $obj["data"];
print_r($obj["data"]);


foreach ($array_data as $row) {
    print_r($row);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test (vid, name,branch,date,time) VALUES ('" . $row["vid"] . "', '" . $row["name"] . "','".$row["branch"]."','".$row["date"]."','".$row["time"]."')";

    echo "$sql<br>";
    $conn->query($sql);
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

And sample of data being sent as string is as below:

```
{"data":[{"vid":"1","name":"raj","branch":"mech","date":"2-Sep-2017","time":"13:03:24 PM"}]}
```

Can u guide if there is something to fix.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says **[you may be at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)**. Learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4712113/5827005). I recommend `PDO`, which I [wrote a function for](http://paragoncds.com/grumpy/pdoquery/#function) to make it extremely easy, clean, and more secure than using non-parameterized queries. Also, [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) may help you choose between `MySQLi` and `PDO`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton +1

Comment: Also note that the data you have shown is not valid json, the strings are not quoted. So `$obj ` will always be empty.

Comment: @jeroen I added method used to create string, probably u can guide there why I m getting wrong format. Ur input is valid.

Comment: @Panache https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329500/sqlite-how-to-get-string-items-using-cursor

check this, you need the getString not getInt

Comment: @Yamen u means whatever I have like int or string or double in SQLite, I will always use getString to get write format?

Comment: JSON is almost always a string, so yes

Comment: And also be carefull about what @GrumpyCrouton said SQL Injection is obvious here.

Comment: @Panache Numbers as values are fine in json, strings ("normal" strings,  dates and times in your example) need to be quoted.

Comment: @jeroen pls guide now as data string issue has fixed. Still no data in server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `cursor.getInt(1)` which will return an integer from the cursor. You need to use `cursor.getString()` in Order to get the string and put them correctly in JSON.

This is a small example:

```
jsonObject.put("vid", curser.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("vid")));
```

Comment: now getting correct format of json, still no data being uploaded? what else left, ps guide.

Comment: 1- check the URL. is it public ? accissable ?
2-  check the connect to db try to add something like this to make sure you are connected : $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','123456') 
       or die('Cannot connect to the DB');

3- try to add some headers URLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

4- echo something on the server to see if you are recieving the request or not: echo json_encode($json));

Comment: glad to help :).